# How to inject Http Parser into OWIN Self host server

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, owin

I have http clients that are sending "POST" requests with no contents which cause the selfhost server to throw http 411 error , the http clients are for customers that it is not a solution to modify them , so the only way to modify my server to not throw this error when "POST" request arrive without content . 
it seem it is happening in the low level , no attribute or filter or even app.Use worked to catch the request before the error get thrown 
it mostly happening at the next level when TCP content get converted to HTTP request.

So basically I am looking for the point when before the server parse the TCP contents into HTTP request

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var baseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8073");

            var config = new HttpSelfHostConfiguration(baseAddress);
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("default", "{controller}");
                   using (var svr = new HttpSelfHostServer(config))
            {
                svr.OpenAsync().Wait();
                Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to quit.");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It turned out the HTTP parser is not inject-able, it is kind of limitation in my openion to any http server , as the trip of data from TCP client until it get converted to HTTP request is black boxed at least in OWIN self host server

Comment: @konzo I had to build TCP server that produce HTTP requests